# PHPUnit mock throws incompatible declaration error

Tags: php, unit-testing, mocking, phpunit

I'm using `PHPUnit 3.6.10` (unfortunately I can't upgrade to newer version at the moment).
While dealing with mocking of some legacy code, I got a weird error. Tried google, only results related to static methods came up, which is not my case.

Having this class:

```
class ServicesMapper extends DbMapper
{
    //... (some methods)

    public function saveTravel(ServiceTravel $oTravel) {
        $this->getAdapter()->insert('services_travels', $oTravel->getToArray());
    }

    //... (some methods)
}
```

I try to mock it:

(inside unit test class)

```
/**
 * @return ServicesMapper
 */
private function getServicesMapperStub()
{
    $stub = $this->getMock('ServicesMapper');

    $stub->expects($this->any())
            ->method('searchBy')
            ->will($this->returnValue(array()));

    return $stub;
}
```

Now, while running this fake test (I know this test does nothing, this is just to show issue):

```
   /**
    * @test
    */
    public function fakeMockTest(){
        $serviceMapper = $this->getServicesMapperStub();
        $this->assertTrue(true);
    }
```

I get this error:

```
Declaration of Mock_ServicesMapper_60b00178::saveTravel() 
should be compatible with ServicesMapper::saveTravel(ServiceTravel $oTravel)
```

I use this style of mocking in a lot of places, it works well except for this particular case. What's wrong with my code?

BTW: I also tried to solve this issue by mocking `saveTravel` method, with no luck.

Comment: I am not sure what your common mock function is doing, as it is not mocking the same class you are testing, but I am assuming you have that covered with the 'Default_Model_Mapper_Services'.  The error is indicating that you have mocked saveTravel() without a parameter, but your test (and the main class) is expecting a parameter of type ServiceTravel.

Comment: Hi! Sorry, had typo in my example. I converted all long class names to short names to make code more readable, but I forgot to change it in one place. Fixed that, updated the question. Also - unfortunately no, `saveTravel()` is not being used nor mocked anywhere in my test or production code I've tested. Double checked.

Comment: In your mock, I noticed you are looking for the method('searchBy'), not the the saveTravel().  This might not be anything, but it does appear to not be catching the call then to use the mock.  Albeit, the error still seems to indicate the difference in your mock (Mock_ServicesMapper_60b00178::saveTravel() and the ServiceMapper::saveTravel(ServiceTravel $oTravel). It still appears the mock is not defined properly.

Comment: I know that they are two different methods. The tricky part is that in all of my tests I use only searchBy, never save travel.

Comment: Not sure then.  I can only assume that the error is accurate, and the saveTravel is getting checked, but is not referenced properly by the mock structure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code looks correct, and might work with simple stubs, not mocks (basically, a stub with expectations).

For mocks you need to do:

```
$mock = $this->getMockBuilder('ServicesMapper')
             ->setMethods(array ('searchBy'))
             ->getMock();
```

All the methods you want to set expectations for should be declared on setMethods().

Comment: Thanks! Gonna try it out!